# RSA algorithm: How to enter the multiplicative inverse to WolframAlpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to enter step 5: Compute d, the modular multiplicative inverse of `e (mod φ(n))`.
How do I enter this in WolframAlpha?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#A_working_example

Answer (score 1):

Technically the multiplicative inverse is equal to `(function)^-1 (1/x) || x^-1`

So presumably you would just enter: `(e (mod φ(n)))^-1`

[image: Which for me yielded:]

Comment: Check the example. e=17. n=3233. (17 (mod φ(3233)))^-1 is not 2753.

Comment: Hrm. Then I'm honestly not sure. I tried `modular inverse of 17 (mod(3120(3233)))` and `(17 (mod φ(3233)))` as input seeing as it accepts it in word form as well. Both yielded 1/17 rather than 2753.

Comment: @JusticeCassel almost, try `modular inverse of 17 mod 3120` and if you have a copy of Mathematica instead, `Solve[17 d == 1, d, Modulus -> 3120]` works.

Answer (score 0):

The modular inverse is a result of the extended gcd, it's shown as part of the `ExtendedGCD` function: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=extendedgcd(17,3233). The result of your example is -1141.

Note, when you're doing homeworks (or just fiddle around), you might want to use a more comfortable tool, I'd recommend Python. The definition of the modular inverse in Python is very simple:

```
def inverse(x, p):
    inv1 = 1
    inv2 = 0
    while p != 1:
        inv1, inv2 = inv2, inv1 - inv2 * (x / p)
        x, p = p, x % p

    return inv2
```

Comment: Heads up: I think you meant `extendedgcd(17,3120)` as you've worked out the extended gcd for e,n not e,phi(n). This then lets you show that `-367` and `2753` are congruent mod 3120: `3120-367=2753`.